# TS2351: How to create constructor typings for `new function()` in ts

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a npm package, that exports default a class. This module is written in es3, but I want to provide `types.ts`

**index.js** (in my package)

```
function MyClass(p1, p2) {
  // code
}

module.exports =  MyClass;
```

Ok, then I created types **index.d.ts** (inside my package, aside index.js):

```
declare module 'mypackageid' {
  interface MyClass {
    new (div: HTMLElement, conf: any): MyClass;
  }
  export var MyClass: MyClass;
}
```

I can easily use this code in es3 and it works. (outside of my package, e.g. from another package)

```
var myInstance = new MyClass()
```

But if I want to use it from another package inside of .ts file:

```
import MyClass from 'mypackageid';

new MyClass(divReference, { // <-- error points to this line
    onBlobPaste: e=> {
      console.log(e);
    },
});
```

Typescript loader refuses to compile and prints:

> TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call
>   or construct signature.

**EDIT 1**:

> You use a commonjs default export in your .ts file, your .d.ts file
>   specifies a member export, and your consumer is expecting an ES6
>   default export. In what way are you actually trying to export it? You
>   have to pick one

I don't explicitly import types, I expect typescript to autodetect types automagically from 'index.d.ts'. If I use default export like this:

```
declare module 'mypackageid' {
  interface MyClass {
    new (div: HTMLElement, conf: any): MyClass;
  }
  export default MyClass
}
```

I will get error below. The error points to line with `new`

> S2693: 'MyClass' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Comment: Please check my edit1. I tried that already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `exports=` approach in you module, and thus replace the whole export of your module, you will need to use `import=`, and a module system that supports this (such as AMD or commonjs). See [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

```
mypackageid.d.ts
declare module 'mypackageid' {
    class MyClass {
        constructor(div: HTMLElement, conf: any);
    }
    export = MyClass;
}


//Usage
import MyClass = require('mypackageid')

new MyClass(null, null)
```

Also if you want to use an interface with `new`, that can't be the export (as it is a type) you need to declare a `const` and export that:

```
declare module 'mypackageid' {
    interface MyClassCtor {
        new (div: HTMLElement, conf: any) : {};
    }
    const MyClass : MyClassCtor;
    export = MyClass;
}
```